# Best practices for secure, separated virtualhost LAMP environment

Tags: debian, security, multiuser

What are the best practices for a Debian Squeeze + Grsecurity/PAX based system when multiple, and therefore insecure, websites must run on the same server? I mean how can I mitigate an attack, so that if UserX's website got hacked, the other hosted sites remain intact etc.? Are there any good guides on this topic?

Comment: perhaps http://serverfault.com is a better site for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by reading http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PrivilegeSeparation